# segue to a child view controller

Tags: ios, segue, uicontainerview

I have a layout where there is a Container View and Multiple Actions (through Gesture Recognizer, through buttons etc). I want the actions to change the controller inside the Container View, preferably by performing a Segue. Also, I want the design of the application to be clean - Child Controllers shouldn't have segues between each other. It should be one parent controller with multiple segues, where each segue change the embedded container. How can I achieve that? The only thing that comes to mind is to create Segues on the fly, which doesn't seem possible in iOS since the storyboard creates them for you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Implementing `- prepareForSegue:sender:` springs to mind here.

Comment: I don't know how to actually build the segues... Like how can I create a segue from Parent to Child... What Segue Type should I use?

Comment: That's a bit to broad for Stack Overflow. What you're asking isn't fit for a Q&A format.

Comment: I think you would have to make a custom segue to so this. You can make as many as you want from the parent controller to other view controllers.

Comment: That's what I needed; I'm going to research it more tomorrow. That way I just overload the perform function and tell it to change the controller in the containerview, right?

Comment: Yep, that's what you would do.